# npm install installs, but node_modules is empty

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-16.04

I have a VM on digital ocean running Ubuntu 16.04. I installed node and git. I am pulling my repo, and trying to install all dependencies.

I run `npm install` inside my project folder. Everything looks to install correctly. Then I try to start my app by running `node server.js` and I get all sorts of `module not found errors`.

When I look inside `node_modules`, the directory is empty.

Any ideas what might be happening?

Output:

```
root@codetrunk-dev:~/codetrunk# npm install --save
npm WARN deprecated swig@1.4.2: This package is no longer maintained
npm WARN deprecated lodash.isarray@4.0.0: This package is deprecated. Use Array.isArray.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
Killed          ...] / extract:alt: verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /root/codetrunk/node_modules/.staging/alt-983484ae/node
root@codetrunk-dev:~/codetrunk# ls
app  bower.json  config.js  gulpfile.js  models  node_modules  package.json  public  server.js  views
root@codetrunk-dev:~/codetrunk# cd node_modules/
root@codetrunk-dev:~/codetrunk/node_modules# ls
root@codetrunk-dev:~/codetrunk/node_modules# ls
root@codetrunk-dev:~/codetrunk/node_modules#
```

Comment: Isn't it all the packages you depend are deprecated. Maybe this is the reason.

Comment: Do you have a package.json file? Try running npm init

Comment: Have you found any solution on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to increase memory of your droplet from 512mb to 1gb, at least to install the npm modules. Then you can go back to 512mb if you want. That fixed it for me.

Comment: +1 You saved me a lot of trouble! Indeed the `Killed` in the logs means that there's not enough memory to unpack.

Comment: Thanks! I never would have figured that out.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that your `package.json` file either does not exist or has no `dependencies`or `devDependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that doesn't require increasing the memory of your droplet (or, if you're not on a server that has that ability) is to manually install dependencies individually or in small groups. In my case, express was the biggest package I was installing, so I installed that manually with `npm install express`, then ran `npm install` to get the rest.